# Count selected elements using Selecter (JavaScript, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the jQuery plugin "Selecter" and I try to count selected elements. I tried to count elements with the css attribute `selected`, but I can't get it right.

```
$("span[style='selected']").length
```

This is how my HTML looks like (one is **selected**):

```
    <div class="selected-options">
       <span class="selecter-item selected" data-value="wtZyXCj99F7kWqhpL">One</span>
       <span class="selecter-item" data-value="gZGMcg8oDHpQsSHui">Two</span>
    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`selected` is class and not style. so use:

```
$("span.selected").length
```